# how to execute a command telnet php

Tags: php

I have a code to connect to a teamspeak server with telnet.
can someone help me sending a command?

my code:

```
<?php
$ip = 'localhost';
$result = '';
$fp = fsockopen($ip, 10011); 
echo fgets($fp); 
      fputs($fp,"help");
      $result=fread($fp,1024); 
fclose($fp);
echo nl2br($result);
?>
```

I want to send the command "help"

this code only returns:

```
TS3 
Welcome to the TeamSpeak 3 ServerQuery interface, type "help" for a list of commands and "help " for information on a specific command.
```

Comment: You're not telnetting. telnet is a program/remote terminal protocol. you're opening a tcp socket.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver , nope that won't change the output

Comment: can you please answer with more details, rather than just returning links..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

something like this:

```
<?php
$socket = fsockopen("localhost", "10011", $errno, $errstr); 

if($socket) 
{ 
    echo "Connected <br /><br />"; 
} 
else 
{ 
    echo "Connection failed!<br /><br />"; 
} 

fputs($socket, "help \r\n"); 

$buffer = ""; 

while(!feof($socket)) 
{ 
    $buffer .=fgets($socket, 4096); 
} 

print_r($buffer); 
echo "<br /><br /><br />"; 
var_dump($buffer); 

fclose($socket); 
?>
```

I added some more to your code, it was impossible to don't

Comment: 2nd parameter of `fsockopen()` should be an integer, representing port number. Also, it does no make sense to continue executing codes when connection failed.